# Is it possible for a SQL query to crash a database

Tags: sql, database, performance, select

So for one of my computing assignments, I need to state, some changes that could not be made since they were out of scope.

One of the changes I intend to talk about is to "Reconsider if acquiring all the reports in a Enterprise Resource Planning software is needed"

My main argument is this, say we have  a ERP software which is hooked to database, the multinational corporation which is utilizing a database, stores approximately 25 million reports.

Can running a SQL query, which retrieves all the reports crash/really slow down the software system/crash the database.

Comment: Yes.  Overloading a database can cause it to slow down to the point where it is non-responsive.  Whether it "crashes" or not depends on your definition of "crashes" and the particular database you are using.

Comment: A recursive common table expression where the basis is never reached will lock up any RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can running a SQL query, which retrieves all the reports crash/really slow down the software system/crash the database.

Our databases run saved searches(TSQL generated by ORM  from frontend),one day we observed SQLSERVER  is very slow and not responsive enough.

We found the cause to be a  sql query generated by ORM and that sql query doesn't have any suitable index and this same query is ran by multiple people as part of their work.

so answer to your question is YES